# postgres How to join data and replace null value

Tags: postgresql

i am still newbie in sql and i have stuck in this Postgres sql problem, can you help me

i have data table like this

| NIk | GROUP | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 201212003 | ENG | M |  |  |
| 201212003 | ENG |  | P |  |
| 201301005 | ENG |  | P |  |
| 201301005 | ENG |  |  | S |

expected result:

| NIk | GROUP | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 201212003 | ENG | M | P |  |
| 201301005 | ENG |  | P | S |

i already try to use any join cant get the result. Please help me

Comment: For your next question, you might want to read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that is your original data, you need to split it into 3 tables, and then do the join.

```
with table_a as (
    select "Nlk", "GROUP", "A"
    from original_data
    where "A" is not null
), table_b as (
    select "Nlk", "GROUP", "B"
    from original_data
    where "B" is not null
), table_c as (
    select "Nlk", "GROUP", "C"
    from original_data
    where "C" is not null
)
select "Nlk", "GROUP", "A", "B", "C"
from table_a
full join table_b using ("Nlk", "GROUP")
full join table_c using ("Nlk", "GROUP")
```

`"` after `ENG` in `GROUP` is ignored

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate using say `max()` (`min()` would also work) which will "flatten" all rows for a given `NIk, GROUP` combo into one line:

```
select NIk, "GROUP", max(A) A, max(B) B, max(C) C
from mytable
group by NIk, "GROUP"
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.